# Is there a k8s finalizer which blocks deletion of namespace?

Tags: kubernetes

Is there any type of finalizer like what we have for PersistentVolumes `kubernetes.io/pvc-protection`, that would block completely deletion of namespace until you delete all of the child objects?

Answer (score 0):

A Namespace won't be removed until its subresources deleted, you don't need finalizers. Why do you think you need finalizer?

[Edited]

You should add a finalizer on the namespace and use the *orphan* deletion cascading strategy. For example you can add the *Namespace.metadata.finalizers[0] = "kubernetes"* finalizer with the `kubectl edit ns <ns name>` command, and when you want to delete it use the `kubectl delete ns --cascade=orphan ns <ns name>` command. It will try to delete the namespace but don't bother the subresources, but because you have a finalizer on the namespace, it won't be deleted immediately. You can delete the subresources by hand and after you will be ready remove the finalizer from the Namespace resource and it will be removed.

Comment: Once you run `kubectl delete ns` command, it will trigger deletion of all subresources as well, and delete namespace itself afterward...

Comment: I need a finalizer if I want kubernetes to completely stop my action of deleting namespace resource until I delete all child objects...

Comment: So if I understand correct, you want to keep the Namespace resource - for some reasnon - despite you use the `kubectl delete ns` command? Finalizers are just custom strings in a list. You can add or remove them by hand (or with an operator) like the labels.

Create a Namespace, edit it with `kubectl edit ns`, add a .metadata.finalizers[0] = "kubernetes" field. Then create a random Pod. After the pod created, run the `kubectl delete ns` command. The Pod will be deleted, but the Namespace remain in Termindated state until you remove the finalizer.

Comment: I want `kubectl delete ns` command not to delete anything, until I manually delete all child objects with many `kubectl delete` commands...

Comment: Add a finalizer on the Namespace and set the deletion cascading strategy to orphan: `kubectl delete --cascade=orphan ns xxx`. The dependent resources are remain untouched, you can / must delete them manually, and after when you remove the finalizer from the namespace it will be removed.

Comment: still not sure which finalizer I can add?